# Strange Vocal Trills (L, Th, and Q)

Tags: phonology, phonetics, ipa, conlang, trills

I’m currently spending my quarantine working on the language for my novel. The language is alien-like, so I wanted to make it extremely difficult in it’s phonology. There are several trills. The trilled L, the trilled Th, and the trilled Q. I started making an IPA chart to show my aunt, a linguist, in order to get her feedback and criticism. But, after searching through many many articles and IPA sounds, I couldn’t find anything similar to the trilled l and the trilled th. I called my aunt, seeing if maybe she had heard them before. She was shocked to hear me pronounce them and she couldn’t do it herself. Does anyone know of any languages that have these sounds? The trilled l is just an l, but trilled, there’s nothing fancy or foreign going on. Same thing for the th, it’s just a th (like “that” in English or “ddraig” in Welsh) but trilled. Q may be a little harder, as it’s a guttural sound but still trilled (somewhat like the breathy r in some French accents but still not similar enough to be written the same). Is anyone else able to replicate these sounds or at least can refer me to languages that use these sounds?

Comment: Can you describe the trills still more precise by stating what body part actually trills? Is it the tip of the tongue, can you make the blade of your tongue vibrate, or some other part?

Comment: "Trilled L" is impossible, whatever sound you pronounce and call it a "trilled L" is actually something different, it can be anything, but surely not "trilled L". The point is, "trill, trilled" is a linguistic term which means quite a specific _manner of production of noise_. Other kinds of the _manner of production of noise_ are: plosive, nasal, fricative, affricate, tap or flap, lateral fricative, approximant, and lateral approximant. Note, each consonant sound can be produced with _just **one** manner of production of noise_, there **cannot be** *plosive fricatives, or *nasal trills.

Comment: A consonant sound can be _either_ a plosive _or_ a fricative,  _either_ a nasal _or_ a trill. In the same way, there **cannot be** any *_trilled lateral approximants_. The L sound, [l] is a lateral approximant as for its manner of production of noise, the slot is occupied, it cannot have one more feature in it. The most probable cause you think you can pronounce "trilled L" is that you actually pronounce [ɮ], a voiced alveolar~dental lateral fricative, and you think it's "trilled L". Listen to [ɮ] [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental_and_alveolar_lateral_fricatives). Is it it?

Comment: I think OP just means repeated, as if the speaker had a stutter.

Comment: As Yellow Sky says, from a purely phonetic point of view, your three consonants are all impossible; they cannot exist by definition. With l and th, both of which are continuants, it is possible to make sounds that combine their place of articulation with the trill manner of production – an interdental trill and a lateral trill. You could also pronounce either with a simultaneous uvular trill (though not easily). With q, however, there is no such possibility. Q is a plosive, which cannot co-occur with trilling. The closest would be a uvular trill itself (like the French r).

Comment: @YellowSky While I agree with most of what you say, I don’t see why nasal and trill should be mutually exclusive; nasality does not in itself specify primary and secondary articulators, just a redirection of the airflow. Nasal trills are not unheard of, and certainly a nasal with concurrent epiglottal trilling is perfectly easily to pronounce and occurs commonly in various ‘hm’-like interjections.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - In many, if not in most languages, interjections use a subset of phones not used in other parts of speech, for example a whistle of surprise/admiration, bilabial and epiglottal trills, different clicks and other implosives, etc. Even a slap with a palm on the forehead can be treated as an interjection since it does make a sound. Not to say about people trying to imitate different animal sounds or sounds of nature (water flowing, wind howling). Apart from clicks and implosives, those phones are hardly ever used in content or function morphemes in the languages of the world.

Comment: @YellowSky I agree with all that (nasal trills have, as far as I know, only ever been claimed as allophones in normal language use), but that doesn’t make them systematically impossible the way an approximant trill or a plosive trill is. They can be pronounced, even if they’re not usually. For the purpose of this asker’s goal, a nasal trill might even be a very good choice since they’re so exceedingly rare and “extremely difficult in its phonology” is what they’re looking for.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - If it goes about suggestions for the OP's purpose, mine is doubly articulated trills, such as a simultaneous alveolar–uvular trill [ʀ͡r]. Theoretically it can be pronounced, with some training, though. ;)

Comment: @YellowSky Or even better, a triply articulated bilabial-alveolar-uvular trill, [ʙ͡rʀ] (yeah, I don’t know how to type that on my phone) – nasalised if you want a real challenge. Alveolar-uvular alone is very easy to me, but the triple one is difficult to pronounce quickly and easily enough to use as a regular phoneme without it becoming over-articulated and too long.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Yes, it would seem like the q sound is most similar to the French r like I said in my post. I thought it was distinct, but that might just be the difference in the way some French speakers say it (I’ve found recordings of really really similar sounds in French rs, but they’re inconsistent).

Comment: @Quapaddraig The difference between q and the French r is that q is a _stop_; it’s equivalent to the difference between a Spanish r (the trill, not the flap) and an English t. As you can probably work out just by trying, you can’t pronounce a t as a trill – it’d no longer be a t. Same thing with a q.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet any idea what this sound might be? It’s the L I described in the post. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GXnpBpkBZ0rnkW-qQQp1UK65muKyklzM/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I think you answered the question. I think the original poster is using imprecise language for exactly the sounds you mention saying. The sound that's like an /l/ but a trill is probably a lateral trill like you say, and the sound that's like "th" but trilled is probably an interdental trill. If those are real speech sounds, please post them in an answer. The sound that's like a q might be a French r.

Comment: @Quapaddraig, how well can you pronounce the French "r" and the /q/ sound? Do you know French or another languages with sounds like this well, so that you can say how your q-like trill differs from it? I personally can't pronounce either of these with confidence, but other people might be able to describe it.

Comment: @Jetpack the trilled L I am referring to is not a lateral trill. If you listen to the recording i posted it sounds different and it’s formed differently too. The interdental trill that you mentioned IS the th sound I was referring to, only mine is voiced and also a little bit different, but definitely similar enough to be notated the same as a distinction between voiced and unvoiced. Thanks for letting me know that it’s an interdental trill! But still, the L sound is not a lateral trill.

Comment: @Jetpack as for the q/r distinction, I’ll try recording it. French r is a bit more breathy, and is also clearly an r sound is most recordings (sometimes closer to an h or the rr in Brazilian Portuguese). The q is formed in the back but there’s no r. Think of it like saying the word aqua (in English) but you say the qu sort of like you would say a cr in French (like croix). However, they’re definitely different, because the r sound is completely gone from my q sound. They sound similar, but there’s no r in my q.

Comment: @Quapaddraig That sound bite sounds to me like a (velarised?) l pronounced with a simultaneous uvular trill, basically [l͡ʀ] (or [ɫ͡ʀ]?). If you put your fingers tightly on your Adam’s apple when producing a French r and then when producing this sound, can you feel the same vibration? Can you feel your uvula vibrating against the very back of your tongue?

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the fact that you've described physical impossibilities, if you can do them, that suggests you mis-analyzed the sounds. There are very many strange sounds in human languages. The first step to doing something with these sounds is to actually capture them, meaning, make some decent recordings (preferable in the context [a__a]). Those sample can be analyzed subjectively by qualified others who have experience in auditory analysis (perhaps your aunt), and acoustically by anyone who knows how to do acoustic analysis (e.g. using Praat). It may not be possible to recover the physiological events from the recordings (it may require somewhat invasive techniques), but acoustic and auditory analysis is the starting point.

I am tempted to call the L example a "buccal trill". This may be what Lovecraft was uttering when he pronounced the name Cthulhu (there don't seem to be any authoritative recordings). The test is, when you produce it, do your cheeks rapidly bounce in and out (presumably on one side)? I agree that it is a trill, which implies a narrow constriction and an alternating cycle of pressure buildup and release as the active articulator is blown aside (reducing pressure, causing the articulator to make contact again, leading to pressure buildup, and so on).

Comment: Here’s a link to my recording of the L sound. I hope this helps. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GXnpBpkBZ0rnkW-qQQp1UK65muKyklzM/view?usp=drivesdk